# If a tortoise lost its shell, would it be naked or homeless?

Tags: zoology

We often call a snail's shell 'house'. But there are also naked snails (=slug).

What about tortoises? Is their shell like a house or an important part of their body? If a tortoise lost its shell, would it be naked or homeless?

Answer (score 8):

The shell of a tortoise is physically attached to the rest of the skeletal structure. That being said, it's simply not possible for a tortoise (or snail, though, for slightly different reasons) to leave its shell.

> If a tortoise lost its shell, would it be naked or homeless?

It would be both naked & homeless, as well as dead.

---

[image]

Comment: That’s a great picture. Where is it from?

Comment: @canadianer I thought so too! I obtained the image from [DK](https://www.dkfindout.com/us/animals-and-nature/reptiles/inside-tortoise/), however, it appears to be widely used throughout the web, so I'm not sure if that's the original source.

Comment: Thanks. I’d love to see how the skeleton moves to retract the head inside the shell.